# Equivalent code in Haskell for !=

Tags: haskell

Is there an equivalent statement, in Haskell, for code similar to the following:

```
x != y
```

For instance:

```
[x+y | x <- list1, y <- list2, x != y]
```

How would I say the last bit: (x != y) in Haskell?

Answer (score 5):

The correct Haskell name is `/=` for the "not equal" comparison operator.

Comment: N.B. `/=` makes sense in some ways because 1. Variables are immutable so operators like `+=, /=, -=` etc aren't in the base language 2. It sort of looks like `≠`.

Comment: Nitpick: `/=` is a normal function, not a "Haskell syntax". `(/=) x y` also works.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I agree, yet I wish Haskell followed the C naming for that, since after all we already share `==,<,>,<=,>=,&&,||` with C. I can understand not using `!` for unary negation (non-alpha names are for binary operators), but `/=` feels unique, compared to other languages (`!=,<>` are fairly common). After getting used to it, I like `/=` on its own, though -- I only wish many languages followed the same notation for very basic operators.

Comment: I suggested != way back when, but I think it was Joe Fasel who decided to go for /= instead.